# How to find out the matching values from column A to Column B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 30 values in my column A and 100 values in column B. I would like to keep values of column A only, need to find out the matching in column B and remove the others. 
Example of values : /x/member/info/text-column

I did try =vlookup(A2,B2:B100,4,FALSE). But it is not working. Could you assist me here.

Answer (score 1):

the forumla should be:

```
=vlookup(A2,$B$2:$B$100,1,0)
```

and then use filter to select the #NA to delete
or

```
=countif($B$2:$B$100,A2)
```

and then use filter to select "0" to delete.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove from column **B** items that are not in column **A**:

```
Sub RowCLeaner()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    For i = 100 To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        Set r = Range("A1:A30").Find(what:=v, After:=Range("A1"))
        If r Is Nothing Then Cells(i, "B").Delete shift:=(xlShiftUp)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to keep this as a excel formula rather than VBA?

Your formula has not worked as you have put `4` when you have only referenced 1 column `b` maybe change the formula to `=vlookup(A2,$B$2:$B$100,1,0)` and see if that works.  That would bring back the value of a repeat or error if it doesnt repeat.  To remove the error you could do this `=iferror(vlookup(A2,$B$2:$B$100,1,0),"")` which would show a blank on any that are not found.

Alternatively you could do a countif which would count how many repeats are found. 
`=countif($B$2:$B$100,A2)` which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$30)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$30,B:B,0))),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

It will return the list of items in A that is in B without any extra steps.

---

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula `FILTER()`:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$30,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$30,B:B,0)))
```